# Map object types using custom converter

Tags: java, inheritance, mapping

I'm trying to design a mapper that will convert one object type to another shown in the diagram below:

[image]

The object has structure as follows (it's not a JSON):

```
{
"type": "DownloadAppComponent",
"name": "Download App",
"contentId": "download-app",
"properties": {
    "iosUrl": "http://apple.com",
    "androidUrl": "http: //google.com",
    "promoText": "Download our app",
    "hidden": false
}
```

My first solution was to have mapper for each type but this required a lot of code duplication to map common attributes (i.e. name, type, contentId).

```
public DownloadAppComponent map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    DownloadAppComponent downloadAppComponent = new DownloadAppComponent();

    downloadAppComponent.setType(cmsDocument.getType()); // <-- this will be duplicated in each mapper
    downloadAppComponent.setName(cmsDocument.getName()); // <-- this will be duplicated in each mapper
    downloadAppComponent.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH)); // <-- this will be duplicated in each mapper
    downloadAppComponent.setIosURL(cmsDocument.getText(IOS_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setAndroidURL(cmsDocument.getText(ANDROID_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(cmsDocument.getText(HIDE_PATH)));
    downloadAppComponent.setPromoText(cmsDocument.getText(DOWNLOAD_PROMO_TEXT_PATH));

    return downloadAppComponent;
}
```

I've been trying to refactor that code and I come up with generic BaseDocumentMapper:

```
public BaseDocument map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    BaseDocument document = documentsMapperFactory.getMapper(cmsDocument.getType()).map(cmsDocument);
    document.setType(cmsDocument.getType());
    document.setName(cmsDocument.getName());
    document.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH));
    return document;
}
```

The `documentsMapperFactory` returns specific mapper that will map only type related attributes and return that object instance.

However there are still more levels in inheritance and I just have one type value which I can resolve to concrete mapper. So I'll have to repeat Component's specific fields mapping in each component mapper. I was thinking that since I know the hierarchy I could create some mappers that will map the documents from Up to Bottom, i.e. create first DownloadAppComponent and then extend it with Component and then with BaseDocument specific properties. However I have not found any good solution except using abstract classes and inheritance in mappers as well.

Could someone advice me if this is good approach or if there are any issues or other better solutions for my case?

Thank you.

Comment: Well, I would first try to use existing libraries, like http://dozer.sourceforge.net/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least three alternatives. The first is the more generic leaving the concept of `CmsDocument` completely separated from `BaseDocument`.

The other two options link `BaseDocument` and `CmsDocument` classes so it is a design choice wich option select.

**First option**
You can create a method to set common values based on the fact that both object derives from `BaseDocument`.

```
....

private void setCommonValues(BaseDocument doc, CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    doc.setType(cmsDocument.getType());
    doc.setName(cmsDocument.getName());
    doc.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH));
}



public DownloadAppComponent map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    DownloadAppComponent downloadAppComponent = new DownloadAppComponent();

    // Call setCommonValues 
    setCommonValues(downloadAppComponent, cmsDocument);

    downloadAppComponent.setIosURL(cmsDocument.getText(IOS_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setAndroidURL(cmsDocument.getText(ANDROID_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(cmsDocument.getText(HIDE_PATH)));
    downloadAppComponent.setPromoText(cmsDocument.getText(DOWNLOAD_PROMO_TEXT_PATH));

    return downloadAppComponent;
}
```

And similarly for the other function

```
public BaseDocument map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    BaseDocument document = documentsMapperFactory.getMapper(cmsDocument.getType()).map(cmsDocument);

    // Call setCommonValues to remove duplication of code
    setCommonValues(document, cmsDocument);
    return document;
}
```

---

**Second option**

Create a method `init` in the `BaseDocument` class

```
private void init(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    this.setType(cmsDocument.getType());
    this.setName(cmsDocument.getName());
    this.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH));
}
```

And in the body of map

```
public DownloadAppComponent map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    DownloadAppComponent downloadAppComponent = new DownloadAppComponent();

    // Call init 
    downloadAppComponent.init(cmsDocument);

    downloadAppComponent.setIosURL(cmsDocument.getText(IOS_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setAndroidURL(cmsDocument.getText(ANDROID_URL_PATH));
    downloadAppComponent.setHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(cmsDocument.getText(HIDE_PATH)));
    downloadAppComponent.setPromoText(cmsDocument.getText(DOWNLOAD_PROMO_TEXT_PATH));

    return downloadAppComponent;
}
```

And similarly for the other function

```
public BaseDocument map(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    BaseDocument document = documentsMapperFactory.getMapper(cmsDocument.getType()).map(cmsDocument);

    // Call init 
    document.init(cmsDocument);

    return document;
}
```

---

**Third option**

Create a constructor on `BaseDocument` taking `CmsDocument` as parameter

```
public BaseDocument(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
    this.setType(cmsDocument.getType());
    this.setName(cmsDocument.getName());
    this.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH));
}
```

And in DownloadAppComponent

```
 public DownloadAppComponent(CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
     super(cmsDocument);
     this.setIosURL(cmsDocument.getText(IOS_URL_PATH));
     this.setAndroidURL(cmsDocument.getText(ANDROID_URL_PATH));
     this.setHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(cmsDocument.getText(HIDE_PATH)));
    this.setPromoText(cmsDocument.getText(DOWNLOAD_PROMO_TEXT_PATH));

 }
```

In this case you don't need a map method, you can directly build the objects calling the constructor with parameters.

---

If you need to have one class with the method `map` that can return two different instances you can pass the required type as parameter:

```
public class Mapper {
    private void setCommonValues(BaseDocument doc, CmsDocument cmsDocument) {
        doc.setType(cmsDocument.getType());
        doc.setName(cmsDocument.getName());
        doc.setContentId(cmsDocument.getText(CONTENT_ID_PATH));
    }

    public BaseDocument map(CmsDocument cmsDocument, Class<? extends BaseDocument> clazz) {
        BaseDocument doc = null;
        if (clazz.getCanonicalName().equals(DownloadAppComponent.class.getCanonicalName()) {
            DownloadAppComponent appComponent = new DownloadAppComponent();
            doc = appComponent;
            appComponent.setIosURL(cmsDocument.getText(IOS_URL_PATH));
            appComponent.setAndroidURL(cmsDocument.getText(ANDROID_URL_PATH));
            appComponent.setHidden(Boolean.parseBoolean(cmsDocument.getText(HIDE_PATH)));
            appComponent.setPromoText(cmsDocument.getText(DOWNLOAD_PROMO_TEXT_PATH));

        } else {
             doc = new BaseDocument();
        }
        setCommonValues(doc);
        return doc;
    }
}
```

You can invoke it as:

```
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
CmsDocument cmsDocument = ...

BaseDocument doc = mapper.map(cmsDocument, BaseDocument.class);

DownloadAppComponent downloadAppComponent = (DownloadAppComponent) mapper.map(cmsDocument, DownloadAppComponent.class);
```

Comment: I have to say that I like the first method more because as you said it doesn't make those two classes dependent and it helps the code to be cleaner by keeping the SoC and Single Responsibility principles. Still I don't understand where I should put that `setCommonValues()` method. They can't be all in the same class because it would not compile. The `map()` method would be ambiguous.

Comment: The helper method has to be called like `super.setCommonValues()` but I have to add another level of inheritance for the mapper classes (i.e. `DownloadAppComponentMapper extends ComponentMapper`, and `ComponentMapper extends BaseDocumentMapper` etc...). Can I avoid it somehow?

Comment: @MariuszMiesiak the methods `map` can be renamed if they must be added in the same class. But you can also create two classes for them without renaming it. If you choose one class with two renamed `map` methods you can add to that class  the method `setCommonValues`. Otherwise the best solution is to create an abstract class with a concrete method `setCommonValue` and an abstract method `map` and create two subclasses for each custom implementation of `map`.

Comment: @MariuszMiesiak if you need to have only one class and one method pass a parameter with the type of class to be created. I add this solution to the answer.